# Handwrite letter V in Inline Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, characters, inline

What package and command do I have to insert to write letter V in a handwriting style using Inline Math Mode?

Below is the result I want to obtain:

[image]

Comment: The font is called Mayfair Regular created by Canada Type. As it does cost money, I can't do an example for you. Just search this site for `fontspec` in order to see how to include an `.otf` font like this one.

Comment: @yo The http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character seems to be not helpful in this case. There is some strange font, probably known to someone from his/her work.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke To me it appears like that the particular font is not of interest, rather the calligraphic/script style. Anyways, font recognition questions are off-topic since they are hardly useful to anybody else than the OP...

Comment: @yo' So it is better to close this as off-topic, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

A version with `\mathcal`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for \mathbb

\begin{document}
  $ \mathcal{V} \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The shape of the symbol depends on the font. An example with `mathptmx` (Times):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for \mathbb
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
$ \mathcal{V} \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result mathptmx]

The same with `mathpazo` (Palatino) instead of `mathptmx`:

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The `.ttf` version of the font Mayfair can be downloaded [here](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Mayfair/). You will have to use Lua- or XeLaTeX in order to get it running, though.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\myV}{\text{{\fontspec{Mayfair.ttf}V}}}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Here is your desired inline math: $\myV\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ 

And back to the normal font again.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, as it is also useful for me, not only OP, as it was suggested in comments. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Glad to hear that.

Comment: :-). BTW: is there any method for offering a bounty for a closed question?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I don't think so.  Especially as I was one of the closers as well... I thought it is off-topic and a dupe to the "identify a math [...] character", but wanted to show the solution anyway. As this is considered rep-baiting, I stay modest and satisfied with your friendly comment.